# Tensor %s is not an element of this graph problem with DeepPavlov library

Tags: tensorflow

I try to make one Tutorial work in colab, and faced some problems.
Most of them (somehow :)) solved, but right now i faced with error:
“tensor %s is not an element of this graph” about last layer of my network.

This is the shared link to the notebook: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1UIDsV2nBwc5jgeNU4WUm_G_Jumr8fRne?usp=sharing 1

Can you, please, help me or give some advise to solve this?

P.S. i’ve changed part of the code in training part to make sure that i can go to interact model.
P.P.S.I've tried some tricks: save and load model, setting default graph and so on (what i've managed to find here), but in the and - i'm failed.